# python hex string to u_char conversion

Tags: python

would like to store "ffffff" hex string (or "ff0a0b0c01" into u_char packet[256] in python.

which can be later sent to C with u_char packet[256]

what is the best way to do that in python 2.7?

Comment: There's quite a few ways to do this. Does the packet need to be 256 bytes? (You can send a "hex string" of that length many ways, most of them much shorter than 256 bytes.) Is the hex string always hex (i.e., is it trivially a number)? How long can it be?

Comment: no the packet can be u_char of any size. 256 is just an example length. idea is to store hex string into u_char array so that it can be decoded as packet of xyz kind by typecasting into structure of u_chars. hex string is hex because packet can be "00 01 ff ee 23"..

Comment: Sorry, more question: what's a "u_char array"? Like, unsigned char array? (Your question is tagged Python: do you mean `bytes`?) Arbitrary sequences of octets are often represented as hex strings; are you trying to send a hex string itself, or something that you're representing above as a hex string? When you say "packet": you are using UDP?